# Why my code won't compile?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
E= \textbf{I_{1}} \cdot R_{1} + \textbf{I_{1}}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no closing bracket for `\textbf{I_{1}`....

Comment: I closed it in the meantime but it still does not work...

Comment: The first `\textbf` directive is still missing a closing curly brace...

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that `\textbf` sets its argument in text mode, and there exists no subscript notation via `_` in text mode.

If you want to highlight certain components of an equation, or use **boldface** inside math mode, consider using `\mathbf` or `\bm` (from [`bm`](//ctan.org/pkg/bm)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  E &= \textbf{I\textsubscript{1}} \cdot R_1 + \textbf{I\textsubscript{1}} \\
  E &= \mathbf{I}_1 \cdot R_1 + \mathbf{I}_1 \\
  E &= \bm{I}_1 \cdot R_1 + \bm{I}_1 \\
  E &= \bm{I_1} \cdot R_1 + \bm{I_1}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to providing the required closing curly brace, I suggest you switch from `\textbf` to `\mathbf`. I.e., something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
E &= \mathbf{I}_{1} \cdot R_{1} + \mathbf{I}_{1}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Note that I wouldn't render the `1` subscripts in bold.

Comment: It works now. I suppose it was because of \textbf . Thank you! :)

Comment: @RoseHamy - That, and because of the missing closing curly brace.

Comment: Any technical reason to prefer to use `\mathbf` instead of `\textbf`?

Comment: with `\textbf` you change math environment to text. consequently you receive error `$` is missing ... with `\mathbf` this is not the case

Comment: @Roboticist - The side-bearings are different for text-mode and math-mode glyphs. Since the code is occurring in math mode, guess which set of side-bearings should be employed?

Comment: @Zarko - The error messages could be avoided by switching from `\textbf{I_{1}}` to `\textbf{I}_{\textbf{1}}`. (Not that I would *recommend* this form, though!) However, it wouldn't address the issue of (potentially incorrect) side-bearings.

Comment: @Mico, i know this, but from op question i conclude that she/he is not aware, that with it change math mode to text one. error arise with wrong use of it. however, there are more work around, one you show in answer, the second and comment above, but the (silly one, since intended bold face is lost) third can be `\textbf{$I_{1}$}` :-)